# How to delete all android contacts that start with a specific name?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

I want to delete all contacts from my android phone that starts with a "AAA" or that contains "AAA" . Here's what I tried:

```java
private void deleteContact(String name) {

        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        String where = ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME + " = ? ";
        String[] params = new String[] {"AAAA"};

        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newDelete(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                .withSelection(where, params)
                .build());
        Log.e(",,,,",String.valueOf(ops.get(0)));
        try {


            cr.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Toast.makeText(NativeContentProvider.this, "Deleted the contact with name '" + name +"'", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

but failed. Please give me some idea so I can proceed further in my project.

Comment: failed how? please detail what error or problem are you getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will get you on the right track:

```
ContentResolver mContentResolver = getContentResolver();
    private int deleteContactsLike(String name) {
    return mContentResolver.delete(
            ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
            + " like ?",
            new String[] { name + '%'});
```

Comment: here is error what i am getting:             android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "=": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, contact_id FROM view_raw_contacts WHERE display_name like = ?

Comment: 1st thing: there should be no "=" in your query.  In my example above it uses a "like" operator.

2nd thing: there should be no "select" statement if you're trying to delete records.  You should be using the content resolver's delete method.

Comment: Sir, Baker , you are doing it ib the right way but i am in startup phase of android, sir can u take remote of my system since i just stuck in the middle of my project due to this problem